# How to import the SAPUI5 Demo Apps SDK to eclipse

Tags: sdk, sapui5

I would like to ask for your help regarding importing of SDK Demo Apps to my eclipse workspace.

I have downloaded the zip file containing the SAPUI5 Demo Apps. When i unzip it, 
i saw the folder containing the demo apps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z9fQ.png)

Now I have tried to import the project in my eclipse, but no project is found whenever i select the folder.

How do i import these demo apps in eclipse? I have searched the internet but i just cant find the right solution.

Your response will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be a bit cheeky here but your first solution might be to NOT use eclipse ;) I am a bit of a Sublime Text fan and with lots of plug ins you can get 90% of the of the functionality with 2% of the memory footprint and an incredibly fast editor.

Ok, with that out of the way, my serious answer to your question would be to create a SAPUI5 project in the normal way (I am going from memory here) 
 File -> New Project (SAPUI5 Project)

Once the shell of that project is created you could then copy the root folder of the tdg project into the shell just created in eclipse.

Repeat this process for each of the examples you want to run in eclipse.

Comment: hi @njames, thank you for your response. i may not be able to follow your first solution, 'coz our team uses eclipse to develop our projects. However, im gonna try your 2nd solution. I was just thinking if there's a way to import without creating my own project. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Cool .. no I don't think there is any way around creating a project.